# Is it possible to set the target-dir only on Linux?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm building on WSL 2 (Ubuntu) and I set build config in .cargo/config:

```
[build]
target-dir = "/home/user/rust-target"
```

I want to add a condition that sets the target-dir only on Linux like this.

Is it better to do this in build.rs?

```
[cfg(target_os = "linux").build]
target-dir = "/home/user/rust-target"
```

Comment: I don't think that's supported. There's dedicated and explicitly documented support for `cfg` keys in the `target` table, not for arbitrary platform gating. So I'd think that's one for the `build.rs`.

Comment: `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` environment variable can also be considered

Comment: I added `println!("cargo:rustc-env=CARGO_TARGET_DIR=/home/user/rust-target");` in build.rs but it seems it doesn't affect anything?